# add attribute label to options dropdown in Magento 1.6

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm trying to add an attribute label to the "Choose an Option" dropdown on the product page , but without hard coding it as I may add other attributes , so for instance i would like to show "Select a size" or Select a Color" .

I have played around and have tried some code from various forums but cant seem to get it to work - any ideas or any suggested extensions

the core code in configurable.phtml is:

```
 <?php
 $_product    = $this->getProduct();
 $_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
```

?>

isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>

```
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose Option')?></option> 
              </select>
          </div>
    </dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

var spConfig = new Product.Config(getJsonConfig() ?>);

```
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just blogged about [an easy solution here](http://zaclee.net/magento/change-default-option-text-for-configurable-products), last week. I didn't want to extend core code since that's a hassle. Here's what I came up with, in short:

---

/~theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

```
<?php
$jsonConfig = json_decode($this->getJsonConfig());
$jsonConfig->chooseText = 'Select ' . $_attribute->getLabel();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo json_encode($jsonConfig); ?>);
</script>
```

---

My blog post has a bit more background information if you're interested.

Comment: Does this work with multiple attributes as well? Because I'm trying this with the product that has Color and Size options. It displays select size for the color option.

Comment: @Ivekua - Yes, only the "chooseText" property is changing in the JSON config. I'd try clearing cache. If that doesn't work it's probably an issue with a plugin you are using, but that would be surprising since this code is so basic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your frontend Javascript changes what the option text is and your PHP can't fix that.

However there is a lot you can do with some frontend code.

If you have just the one predictable option, e.g. size, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    // if only one drop down then set it to 'choose size'. If 'One Size' set value and hide
    if($$('select.super-attribute-select').length==1) {
        $$('select.super-attribute-select')[0].options[0].update('Choose Size');
        if($$('select.super-attribute-select')[0].options.length==2) {
            $$('select.super-attribute-select')[0].options[1].selected=true;
            $$('select.super-attribute-select')[0].up().hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

This also hides the drop-down if there is only one size.

To extend this approach and have it work for any drop-down you may want to get the label value for each drop-down from the page:

```
    $$('select.super-attribute-select').each(function(element) {
    element.options[0].update('CHOOSE ' + element.up().up().previous().down().innerHTML.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").replace(/\*/g, '').toUpperCase());
    if(element.options.length==2) {
        element.options[1].selected=true;
        element.up().up().up().hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your help , I've used Zachary Schuessler option as it seems simpler...

Comment: Actually that is what I will be doing too! Thanks for the comment as I would not have noticed.

Answer (score 0):

The previous snippets are only a solution for a single dropdown attribute on the product page. Here is a solution for multiple dropdown attributes.

First of all edit the markup for the option tag like this (app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml):

```
<option><?php echo $this->__('Choose %s...', $_attribute->getLabel()) ?></option>
```

Now we have to add a string for the first option per attribute in the JSON config, because the dropdown items will be created with JavaScript in the frontend. So, we iterate through the Super Attributes (same file like above):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <?php
   $jsonConfig = json_decode($this->getJsonConfig());
   if (!empty($jsonConfig->attributes)) {
       foreach ($jsonConfig->attributes as $key => $attribute) {
           $jsonConfig->attributes->$key->chooseText = $this->__('Choose %s...', $attribute->label);
       }
   }
   ?>
   var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo json_encode($jsonConfig); ?>);
</script>
```

Now the JSON is extended, but the Magento JS don't use the entry. So, we need to modify the file js/varien/configurable.js at line 172. Change this:

```
element.options[0].innerHTML = this.config.chooseText;
```

into:

```
element.options[0].innerHTML = this.config.attributes[attributeId].chooseText;
```

Now we have the right option label at page load, after dropdown change and for multiple super attributes per page.